# Order by an ActiveRecord model property through a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have connections to things. The connection goes up and down. I want to keep a history of the status and know the connection's current status. I have a Connection model. The Connection has many ConnectionStatus. First I want to create a property on Connection that is the current status which also limits the columns from ConnectionStatus. I've done this so far:

```
class Connection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :connection_statuses, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  def current_status
    status = connection_statuses.first
    status.nil? ? 'unknown' : status.description
  end
end
```

I do not know how to accomplish ordering by current_status. Here are a few desired usages to help explain

```
Connection.first.current_status == :disconnected
Connection.where(:current_status => :disconnected)
Connection.order('current_status desc') # or equivalent
Connection.offset(10).limit(10).order('current_status desc') #pagination
```

This is a general concept that I am not grasping. Thanks for any help here!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're describing since `current_status` as you've defined it is a model method, not a table attribute, so it can't be used in an ActiveRecord relation. But you can alias the has_many relation with a limit to only the first record.

You could do it this way...

```
class Connection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :connection_statuses, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  has_many :current_connections, -> { order(created_at: :desc}.limit(1) }, class_name: 'ConnectionStatus'
```

that lets you do...

```
disconnected_items = Connection.join(:current_connections).where("connection_statuses.description = 'disconnected'")
```